# Off-Canvas Navigation Sliding Feature

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation, translate3d

So I've been playing around with this off-canvas navigation from Foundation and have gotten pretty far with it. I have a list of menus with submenus inside them, all positioned to the left of my page. Here is my code right now:

```
<ul class="uppercase off-canvas-list">
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">List 1</a>
            <ul class="left-submenu">
                <li class="back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Name 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Name 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Name 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">List 2</a>
            <ul class="left-submenu">
                <li class="back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Name 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Name 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Name 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">List 3</a>
            <ul class="left-submenu">
                <li class="back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Name 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Name 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Name 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Now when you click on one of the  the submenu slides in from the right. I was wondering if there was any way to get it to slide in from the left. I tried changing the class on the child ul of that li to "right-submenu" and that doesn't seem to work. Anyone know of any other options that might work?

The CSS file that I am using is the default foundation.css file. I am also using the off-canvas.js and foundation.js files, but those haven't been manipulated at all. I feel like the problem lies in the CSS file. Here is the class that  is given when it slides in from the right:

```
.left-submenu.move-right 
{
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}
```

Maybe editing this part to get it to slide in from the other side is what I need to do? I tried changing the values to 100% but that just pushed it all the way to the left and off the other side underneath the main content. Any help?

Comment: You need to say more here. Your problem comes from either CSS or javascript (and knowing Foundation, it's likely to be CSS). So what the community needs to help you here is either the CSS you have or the name of the plugin you are using.

Comment: The CSS is a very large file so I'm not quite sure how to share it. It's the foundation.css default file if that helps at all

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for anyone else who comes across this issue:

In the foundation.css file there is a class titled .left-submenu. Change the following values to what I have changed them to:

```
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-transform: translate(100%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
```

Then in the styles for the class .left-submenu.move-right, change the following to what I have below:

```
    -ms-transform: translate(0%, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0); }
```